# CSS Grid: how to make grid cell a hyperlink target?

Tags: css, html, css-grid

I am designing a simple two-column layout with CSS Grid; the grid areas are named Cell1 and Cell2.  In the left column (Cell1) I want a list of hyperlinks; when a hyperlink is clicked, I want the content to open in the right column (Cell2).

I think I could use bookmarks to content already loaded into Cell2, but I prefer a way to display content in the right cell when a link is clicked, without using bookmarks.

Using a CSS Grid layout, is there any way to designate a cell where content should go when a hyperlink is clicked, other than the cell that contains the hyperlinks -- using bookmarks or anything else?

Thanks very much for any info.

Comment: Can you please add relevant code because it is quite hard to help when you don't know what to help with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but is much easier to do if you are permitted to use JavaScript/jQuery. Here is an example of using HTML and CSS only to accomplish what you need:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}
.tabs .tab {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}
.tabs .tab:nth-of-type(1) .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
.tab:target a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tab:target .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">      
  <div class="tab" id="tab1">
    <a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <div class="content">Content of Tab1</div>
  </div>    
  <div class="tab" id="tab2">
    <a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <div class="content">Content of Tab2</div>
  </div>      
  <div class="tab" id="tab3">
    <a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
    <div class="content">Content of Tab3</div>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I hoped to do this without javascript, so I will implement your ideas and see if it works.  Otherwise it will have to be javascript.  I'll post back here to let you know how it goes.  Thanks again.

Comment: Adam, I may be missing something in your answer.  I don't see a CSS grid layout here.

Comment: @RTC222 The example makes use of the context of the clicked element to identify which content block should be displayed. If you would prefer to avoid this restriction, you will need to use JavaScript as that will allow you to specify where the desired content sits in the DOM.